# Can I implement Firebase authorization for Google Cloud CDN URL?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-cdn

I have a Firebase project where authenticated users can upload photos to storage bucket. I have my Google Cloud CDN setup properly to the storage bucket. Obviously the bucket contents are available to the world now. How may I use Firebase authentication with Google Cloud CDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly protect Cloud CDN content with Firebase Authentication, but you can prevent content served by Cloud CDN from being accessed publicly.

[Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls) can be used to generate per-user, time-limited URLs that will only serve the content to that given user. Your application backend can sign and then issue these signed URLs.

Users trying to access content without a Signed URL will receive a HTTP 403 unauthorized.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.